# How can I change the chunk size of an existing hdf5 file?

Tags: c#, hdf5

I'm wanting to study how the chunk size in an hdf5 effects our performance, and so I'd like to write something that will let me easily change the chunk size of an existing file containing several datasets so that I can profile the performance.  I can't find a lot of info on this, but maybe I'm not using the wrote vocabulary in my google searches.

Is this possible without duplication?  If not, no problem.  I'm just not sure what the most straightforward way of going about this is.  Any and all help is appreciated!

I'm using C# and HDF5DotNet.  I know that that wrapper isn't supported anymore and we plan on moving to what is supported soon.  But that has not happened yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the h5repack tool. You clone an existing file with different storing options.

- https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/index.html
- https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Repack

*h5repack - Copies an HDF5 file to a new file with or without compression/chunking*

You can use it to do something like:

1. Original file A.
2. Convert A to file B using h5repack tool, with option  *--layout=layout* and the chunksize that you want.
3. Test with file B whatever you want.
4. Delete file B.
5. Repeat from step 2, with another chunksize.